# Jquery hover keep firing on a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is that when users mouse over each name in the list, the div with id preview will have background image. The first `a` does not have a problem, but when I added the `href`, JavaScript keep firing the hover event. What is the problem here?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a>John</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tom</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(function() {
  var names = $('a');
  var bg = document.getElementById('preview');

  names.hover(
    changeBackground, handlerOut
  );

  function changeBackground(e) {
    console.log('hover');
    var image = 'http://londonalley.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/creativesUS3bb-1920x1080.jpg';
    if (bg.style.cssText.length == 0) {
      bg.style.cssText = builtStyle(image);
      bg.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  function builtStyle(image) {
    return "width: 100%;height: 100%;opacity: .6;position: absolute;top:0px;left: 0px;z-index: 101;opacity:.9: 1;display: block;visibility: visible;background-image: url(" +
      image + ");"
  }


  //handle mouse leaves
  function handlerOut() {
    console.log('out');
    if (bg.style.cssText) {
      bg.style.cssText = "";
    }

  }
});
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rattanak22/q96a6dz4/

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between with and without the href value. Seems to be a problem all around.

Comment: @Scott If you keep your mouse over Tom or Sam, the mouse pointer keep blinking.

Comment: yeah and it keeps blinking over "John" too. That was my point. The href has nothing to do with it.

Comment: When you open console, you can see the log keep coming. I am suspecting the problem comes from the href, but not entirely sure.

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p16hfeg0/1/

Comment: or https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p16hfeg0/2/ - using pointer events

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks a lot I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:** Simply change your z-index css in the `builtStyle` function from 101 to -1

```
z-index: -1;
```

**Note:** You have specified opacity twice in your CSS.

Comment: great suggestion. However, changing z-index works for this snippet, but won't work on my site: http://lucid.delappdesign.com/directors/. Because when z-index -1, background won't show up.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you failed to give an example that is a replica of your issue. I will however look at your site and attempt to see what the further issue is.

Comment: I will update my question. I thought fixing A will also fix B. Thanks.

Comment: Your site requires authentication to view it. Do you have a temporary test username and password?

Comment: Thanks, checking now for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting background image as absolutely positioned without z-index. So when you hover over "a" tag, changeBackground function assigns an background image which is absolutely positioned with no z-index. That will bring image on top above all, like one more layer above "a" tag. As this new layer comes up, mouse cannot reach "a" tag which triggers hoverOut, and the cycle continues for every mouse moment.

```
function builtStyle(image) {
return "width: 100%;height: 100%;opacity: .6;position: absolute;top:0px;left: 0px;z-index: -1;opacity:.9: 1;display: block;visibility: visible;background-image: url(" +
  image + ");"
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/pradosh987/9p0pjtd4/

I have assigned -1 z-index to background image and that works.

Comment: You pasted a password protected link.

Comment: Your javascript (on the 2nd link) is linking to localhost resource files.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your site, simply, change your css rules to:

```
#content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 102;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#preview{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Note that this assumes your original `z-index: 101` on `#preview`